# Title / Author of a short story about a man reassembled by aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

There was this short story (I think it was not a standalone novel) about a man who was abducted by aliens, dismantled and remodelled so that his body works better. 
He was in some sort of mental hospital with a girl (another patient) who tried to commit suicide. 
I'm sure I've seen a cover with a man whose nose looks more like a small trunk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds like *Thorns* by Robert Silverberg. A novel rather than a short story.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorns_(novel))

> ...Minner Burris, a space explorer who was captured and surgically
>   altered by aliens on the planet Manipool, and Lona Kelvin, a
>   17-year-old girl who donated eggs for a fertility experiment that
>   produced a hundred babies. Burris, whose freakish appearance draws
>   attention whenever he ventures out in public, has withdrawn into
>   seclusion and bitterness. Kelvin, whose brief fame as the virgin
>   mother of an army of children has begun to fade, has twice attempted
>   suicide because she has not been allowed to adopt or even see any of
>   her offspring.

Some covers at [librarything](http://www.librarything.com/work/167604/covers/1493192)